# Is it good validation to write html table inside html li tag

Tags: html, html-table, html-lists

I have written this code and want to know if this is a good solution to have a `table` inside a `li` tag as I have 2 tables ? And I dont want to show `li` bullet in front of my table.

Here is my code:

```
<ul id="widget_update">
    <li id="Fahrzeuge"><img src="arrow.png" alt="move" width="16" height="16" class="handle" />
        <table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
        <tr>
            <td id="fahrzeuge">

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </li>
    <li id="NEWS"><img src="arrow.png" alt="move" width="16" height="16" class="handle" />
        <table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td id="news">          
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, on modern designs, `ul` and `li` and preferred way to make a layout, that's way more flexible than `tables` and compatible with responsive design. But why do you need it here ?

Comment: tables should only be used for tabular data - as your tables only have one cell I would say that using a table in this case would be wrong.  To remove the bullets add `list-style:none` to the `ul` styles or `list-style-image: url(arrow.png)` then you wouldn't need the actual image tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use divs in this case which will remove the bullets automatically and no css fixes will be required. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s53xx/)

```
<div id="widget_update">
 <div id="Fahrzeuge"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-SWOcB8HK24k/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/idI3VNCg4KI/photo.jpg" alt="move" width="16" height="16" class="handle" />
    <table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
      <tr>
        <td id="fahrzeuge">

        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
<div id="NEWS"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-SWOcB8HK24k/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/idI3VNCg4KI/photo.jpg" alt="move" width="16" height="16" class="handle" />
    <table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td id="news">          
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but i have question can i pass div id same like ul id in jquery because i want to make this table sortable using ajax ?

Comment: u can always pass the div id or better u can create a class with the same name and sort it in jquery

Comment: ohh ok thanks i need a bit help from you more.. i am trying to write my jquery for this but getting error...i want to pass this div id Fahrzeuge and News  value now through ajax to dashboard.php so that i can update my database in sortable way using this value...please check the updated fiddle here :http://jsfiddle.net/s53xx/1/

Comment: u using any jquery plugin to do the same? add it as an external source

Comment: u can try this for a start http://jsfiddle.net/s53xx/2/ over here click on the second div and you would get the id in an alert box. Please mark the answer as approved if it is working at your end.

Comment: hi please check the changes here : http://jsfiddle.net/s53xx/5/... just a small mistake i am doing ....i want to make this table sortable and pass the value through ajax

Comment: Hi u can see updated fiddle now here http://jsfiddle.net/s53xx/7/ its sorting table now just i need to pass the value now ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56706/discussion-between-v31-and-user3702602).

Comment: thanks man now its passing id with postion just while checking in firebug with answer i am getting error with that : TypeError: data is null
$('#widget').html(data.html);

Comment: yeah data will be null as the url is not an absolute path and it is not hitting ur service i suppose

Comment: Hi i have small question in this ...in this jsfiddle i am getting current widget with their position but i also want to get old widget with their position so that  it will be easy for me to store in the database..do you knw how to do that ? so it will be current widget,current position,old widget,old position ...

Comment: i guess for that u need to create a map intially and update the map accordingly

Comment: i have updated fiddle now : http://jsfiddle.net/s53xx/23/  in this i am taking everything in 1 variable i want to separate it now with index,old position and index with new position..and i think its done then...